# Can I add a unique code for each user based on the location?

Tags: users, user-registration, user-meta

I am trying to create a unique code for each user based on the location he/she adds when registering.

For example:
User from UAE: 971-0001
then a user from Egypt: 020-0002

Can this be done? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Yes sure. How do you determine the location - do you have a geolocation plugin or service set up? Or are you taking the country from a registration form? How do you map UAE to 971 - is that the international dialing prefix? Then if you want separate counters per country somewhere you'll either have to track that or search for the last user from that country to get the new number, then you can store this in user meta. Which bit do you need help with?

Comment: @Rup each country is mapped via the dialing code as you stated and it can be read from the country in the registration form and/or geolocation, I have that set too. But I want to generate that code automatically for each customer and have it appear for them in the woocommerce my-account page. I hope this makes it clearer and many thanks for replying.